# How to call Strings between methods?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, methods

So I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a text RPG in java. Whenever I try to call the name of the character in a method other than where the character's name had been set, it returns as null. Are there any solutions for this? I'm not sure which bits to cut out, because they may be important, so here is the entire program.

code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class RPG {
    static int health;
    static int enedamage;
    static int Low = 10;
    static int High = 100;
    static Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int eventnum = 0;
    static String[] enemies = {"goblin", "bat", "skeleton", "beast", "guard", "demon"};
    static String Char;
    static String occup;
    static String weap;
    static int Enehealth;
    static int weapondmg;
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        System.out.print("Input character name:");
        String Char = kbReader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input character occupation:");
        String occup = kbReader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Input character weapon:");
        String weap = kbReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("And so "+Char+" the brave "+occup+" sets out on their journey, brandishing their mighty "+weap);
        System.out.println(Char+" the " + occup +" kills a " + enemies[(int)Math.round(Math.random()*5)]+" with their "+weap+"!");
        weaponroller(100,90);
        System.out.println(weapondmg);
        eventroller(2,1);
        event();
    }

    public static void event(){
        if (eventnum == 1) {
            System.out.println(Char+"walks into a deep dungeon; who knows what they'll encounter here...");
            enemyroller(50,45,25,15);
            System.out.println(Char+" encounters a "+enemies[(int)Math.round(Math.random()*5)]+"!");

        }
        if (eventnum == 2) {
            System.out.println(Char+" walks into a dense forest; its misty echoes are unsettling...");
            enemyroller(50,45,25,15);
            System.out.println(Char+" encounters a "+enemies[(int)Math.round(Math.random()*5)]+"!");

        }

    }
    public static void weaponroller(int a, int b) {
        Random r = new Random();
        High = a;
        Low = b;
        weapondmg = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }
    public static void enemyroller(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        Random r = new Random();
        High = a;
        Low = b;
        enedamage = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
        High = c;
        Low = d;
        Enehealth = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }
    public static void eventroller(int a, int b) {
        Random r = new Random();
        High = a;
        Low = b;
        eventnum = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }
    public static void charrunner(int a, int b) {
        Random r = new Random();
        High = a;
        Low = b;
        health = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }


}
```

Comment: Making everything `static` is a sign of poor OO design. Here you are ***shadowing*** `static` fields. Remove the type name before the field where you set the values. `String Char = kbReader.nextLine();` means the `Char` field is `null`.

Comment: Unrelated, but camelCase naming is the Java convention and it aids readability. Although I'm not sure what you're asking. It's also not clear to me why you keep redefining (the improperly-named) High and Low instead of just using the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple problems with your code. I'm going to try and explain why you're seeing problems:

- You have at least two scopes within the RPG class above:

  - `static` scope - Anything declared `static` is basically a global value for the class.
  - `main` scope - Anything declared in here is "active" only within the context of that `main` method. So,
- You're instantiating variables multiple times, with the *same name*, in different scopes (in this case, static and main).  For example, your `String Char` variable is defined as static (global), but then you redefine it inside your main method again, and assign it whatever the user inputs from the keyboard.  This reuse of variable names, also called *shadowing*, is allowed but you have to be clear about which one you're using. If you change the value for one, the other one doesn't know about the change.  That's why shadowing, in general, is not recommended, since it's easier to make mistakes in your code.
- In your code example, you assign the `main` scoped `Char` the character name input by the user, but when you're printing out the character name inside the `event` method, the only `Char` in scope is the `static` one, *which has never been initialized*.  That's why you're getting a `null` value when you try and print that out.
- The camelCase for the variables is inconsistent, which leads to confusing code.  Class names should be capitalized (e.g. `RPG` is good), but *variable* names should be camel-cased and ideally not shortened, so it's clear what they represent (`characterName` instead of `Char`)
- `static` variable usage is discouraged in Java/OO programming, since you can do almost everything with properly scoped private/public variables.  For a simple example such as this, though, it's ok to use them.

To fix the problem you mention, instead of re-instantiating a `Char` name inside the `main` method, you should simply use the global `Char` and assign it the value the user inputs.

Here's my take on a "fixed" RPG class.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RPG {

static int health;
static int enemyDamage;
static int eventnum = 0;
static String[] enemies = {"goblin", "bat", "skeleton", "beast", "guard", "demon"};
static String character;
static String occupation;
static String weapon;
static int enemyHealth;
static int weaponDamage;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input character name:");
    character = kbReader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input character occupation:");
    occupation = kbReader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input character weapon:");
    weapon = kbReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("And so " + character + " the brave " + occupation + " sets out on their journey, brandishing their mighty " + weapon);
    System.out.println(character + " the " + occupation + " kills a " + enemies[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * 5)] + " with their " + weapon + "!");
    weaponRoller(100, 90);
    System.out.println(weaponDamage);
    eventRoller(2, 1);
    event();
}

public static void event() {
    if (eventnum == 1) {
        System.out.println(character + " walks into a deep dungeon; who knows what they'll encounter here...");
        enemyRoller(50, 45, 25, 15);
        System.out.println(character + " encounters a " + enemies[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * 5)] + "!");

    }
    if (eventnum == 2) {
        System.out.println(character + " walks into a dense forest; its misty echoes are unsettling...");
        enemyRoller(50, 45, 25, 15);
        System.out.println(character + " encounters a " + enemies[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * 5)] + "!");

    }

}

public static void weaponRoller(int a, int b) {
    Random r = new Random();
    weaponDamage = r.nextInt(a - b) + b;
}

public static void enemyRoller(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    Random r = new Random();
    enemyDamage = r.nextInt(a - b) + b;
    enemyHealth = r.nextInt(c - d) + d;
}

public static void eventRoller(int a, int b) {
    Random r = new Random();
    eventnum = r.nextInt(a - b) + b;
}

public static void charrunner(int a, int b) {
    Random r = new Random();
    health = r.nextInt(a - b) + b;
}
}
```